# HTML CSS "position: relative" not well displayed in Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 Android 4.0.4

Tags: android, css, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a hybrid application with this main HTML.

```
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="AppBody" >
            <div>
                <section id="hoy">
                    pppppppp 
                </section>      
                <section id="productos"> 
                    kkkkkkkkk
                </section>
            </div>

            <div>
                <section id="rendimiento"> 
                    lllllllllll
                </section>
            </div> 
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

And the CSS:

```
#AppBody {
    display: -webkit-box;
}

section#hoy{
    width: 94%;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}

section#productos{
    width: 94%;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 5px;
    position: relative;
}

section#rendimiento{
    width: 94%;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
}
```

In my laptop with Chrome it is displayed correctly. Also in my Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini with Android 4.1.2

In Safari and in an iPad it is also well displayed.

But in Samsung Galaxy Tablet 10.1 with Android 4.0.4 the third div is displayed below the previous divs, not on the top in parallel to the other divs.

Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: Impossible to diagnose without code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You are right, I forgot the test case. I have edited the question to add the test case code.